# Node.js // I want a function to wait for a variable until it runs

Tags: node.js, discord.js, export

I am working on a Discord Bot that allows a user to store data in a map. Currently I have gotten up to the point of being able to send the data I want correctly but It was hardcoded to send that exact data set and that's not what I want.

[Hard Coded data sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMtLk.jpg)

I want the user to be able to type a command and have the bot then process which data set it'll need to process. Processing Logic below.

```
function arrayproccesor() {
  const cmd = require("./bot-logic");

  let msg = "";

  for (let [x, y] of a.get(cmd)) {
    msg += x + ":" + y + "\n";
  }
  module.exports = msg;
}
```

as you can see above I tried to import a variable from the command logic, which I had hoped would fetch me the map index that I wanted. Command Logic below.

```
command(client, "udft", (message) => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

      .setColor("#fabe07")
      .setImage(
        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d8/28/f1/d828f1f1a67ac7d03195a9964fb16f94.jpg"
      )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setURL("https://undefeated.com/account/login")

      .addFields({
        name: "ACCOUNTS:",
        value: msg,
        inline: true,
      })
      .addFields({
        name: "STORE:",
        value: "Undefeated \n \n **LINK:**\n",
        inline: true,
      });

    message.channel.send(embed);
  });
```

I tried to define the cmd variable once the user typed the command !udft and export said variable to the arrayprocessor function, but it didnt quite work that way, I think that the function processed nothing therefore making it send [object Object]

[object object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHYK4.png)

Full Code: [Array Proccesor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzkvQ.jpg) [Command Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2lyV.png)

Also I know I could probably put the array and its function in the same file as the command logic but I want to further deal with exporting variables from file to file.

Anyways, Any and all help is appreciated and I'm sorry if I made this longer than it need to be !

Comment: `[object Object]` means that msg is an object and not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async/Await is a useful way to handle Promises in a hoisted manner.
Please read the docs and implement "async / await".
Here's the link: [Click](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#how-do-promises-work)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.